# Problem with the creation of a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Le code :

```
expeditions_success_20 = success_expedition[(success_expedition.members == 1:20)]
```

I don't understand how I can put after the "==", the values 1 to 20 without having to write them with |.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `success_expedition[success_expedition.members.between(1, 20)]`.